# Merging Time Machine Backups to a Single External Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk, macos

I currently have two Time Machine external drives, but I want to move to using just one (I'd still have more than one backup, as I also use Backblaze).  Is it possible to merge the two different backup folders from the individual drives into a single backup folder on one of the drives (or possibly to an entirely new drive)?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have two disks for TimeMachine backups?
If yes: when they have started on the same date, they are fully the same, so you can just format one and use it for something else.
If one started later than the other, I would take the newer one to reformat.
assuming both are ending at the same time: now.

Comment: I did start using them at the same time.  However, I often back up my Mac to each drive at completely separate times.  This means that the two drives don't have the same backup versions.  I'm concerned that I'd lose some important data if I only keep one of the two, so I'm wondering about moving both to a single new (larger) drive and then merging them.  Is that at all possible?

Comment: You can't "merge", because backups are just "changes" to the earlier files.
The principles and workings of TimeMachine are on: Pondini.org Read there and you can answer your question yourself.

Comment: Hi LexS, we try to do more than provide link only answers to improve readability and insure against sites going down. Can you add whatever relevant bits to your answer please?